# Issue with Sqlalchemy and inserting array of jsonb to postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

So i'm trying to insert an array of jsonb values into my database but I can't seem to format it right, here's my code:

```
updated_old_passwords.append({"index": 1, "password": hashed_password})
user.old_passwords = updated_old_passwords
user.last_password_reset = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
db.session.commit()
```

And here's the error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "old_passwords" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 1: ...-01-05T06:18:24.992968'::timestamp, old_passwords=ARRAY['"\"...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
 [SQL: 'UPDATE users SET password=%(password)s, last_password_reset=%(last_password_reset)s, old_passwords=%(old_passwords)s WHERE users.id = %(users_id)s'] [parameters: {'users_id': 1, 'password': '$6$rounds=656000$b.LVoVb7T0WNbT.n$l9uUb1a1qk2Z5ugfpI7B.3D02sUVqhES5VhM1TvwUnMd/iZZL3gn4/zExB47/ZQYPcTMRxO1iaL4/yjXda2.P1', 'last_password_reset': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5, 6, 18, 24, 992968), 'old_passwords': ['"\\"{\\\\\\"index\\\\\\": 1, \\\\\\"password\\\\\\": hashed_password}\\""']}]
```

Any idea how I format my insert for this to work?

Here's my db table

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB, ARRAY

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), index = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    last_password_reset = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    old_passwords = db.Column(ARRAY(JSONB))
```

I also tried this:

```
updated_old_passwords.append(cast('{"index": 1, "password": hashed_password}', JSONB))
```

but got the error

```
StatementError: (exceptions.TypeError) <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Cast object at 0x10f3ed150> is not JSON serializable [SQL: u'UPDATE users SET password=%(password)s, last_password_reset=%(last_password_reset)s, old_passwords=%(old_passwords)s WHERE users.id = %(users_id)s'] [parameters: [{'users_id': 1, 'password': '$6$rounds=656000$WYOiWMAYDSag9QIX$YSDtZle6Bd7Kz.cy7ejWq1NqgME.xUPiDHfV31FKobGu2umxoX34.ZP2MrUDxyym0X4fyzZNEIO//yS6UTPoC.', 'last_password_reset': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5, 6, 26, 35, 610703), 'old_passwords': [<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.Cast object at 0x10f3ed150>]}]]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132714/check-if-a-value-exists-in-json-encode-array-in-mysql/41132962#41132962 that's mysql but it's still valid

Comment: And this postgresql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134260/django-jsonfield-inside-arrayfield/41134445#41134445

Comment: @e4c5 yes I could normalize, I pretty much need to store the last 10 passwords a user used and not allow them to re-use when resetting. So when a new password is added need to pop off the 10th used password.

Comment: yeah, that's a reasonable situation for use of JSONB. I've used it with django but not sqlalchemy so can't give you specific syntax. However since it doesnt' sound like you are going to be doing any lookups on this field. Why not just Array ?

Comment: @e4c5 I wasn't sure if Array will always be the same order since I have to pop off the last one. In that case I could

Comment: arrays maintain order

Comment: `user.old_passwords = cast(updated_old_passwords, ARRAY(JSONB))` instead of a list of cast sql expressions, in case you still need such a construct somewhere. This'll cast the `text[]` to `jsonb[]` server side. It's not pretty, but haven't been able to figure anything nicer out.

Comment: @BrianL.Clark Did you find an answer. can you update it here.

Answer (score 1):

Add the missing cast, using:

```
class CastingArray(ARRAY):

 def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
     return cast(bindvalue, self)
```

And when defining the module use this class instead of `ARRAY` (`old_passwords = db.Column(CastingArray(JSONB))`

(Answer taken from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/oB4zVgUEMgA)