# Insert Array of JSONB with Sqlalchemy in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, jsonb

I have an issue with inserting array of JSONB in postgresql.
The issue is related to [Issue with Sqlalchemy and inserting array of jsonb to postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479654) but there is no answer yet.

Following the indications of http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#using-json-jsonb-with-array, the column is defined of type :

```
myKeyOfJsonbArray=db.Column(CastingArray(JSONB))
```

with the class :

```
class CastingArray(ARRAY):
    def bind_expression(self, bindvalue):
        return cast(bindvalue, self)
```

I redefine the init function as:

```
def __init__(self, attributes):
    for key in attributes:
        if key==myKeyOfJsonbArray:
            temp=[]
            for object in attributes[key]:
                temp.append(object)
            print str(temp)
            setattr(self,key,temp)
        else : 
            ...
```

The print statement prints well the array :
[{u'price_list_id': u'retail', u'value': u'10.0'}]

but psycopg2 returns can't adapt type 'dict' when trying to set the attribute.

a cast temp.append(cast(object,JSONB)) return can't adapt type 'Cast'...
I tried tons of solution (eg. with jsonb_build_object) but I can't figured it out.
Please if someone already met this problem! Thank you!

EDIT

as the line

```
psycopg2.extensions.register_adapter(dict, psycopg2.extras.Json)
```

seemed to did the trick, a more complex dict still cause a problem.

Comment: `CastingArray` works fine for me. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Hello @univerio, it is a bit difficult to provide a full MCV example, but i will try.