# schema for Column(ARRAY(JSON))

Tags: python, model, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

In my model , I have a field as following. I am using sqlalchemy.

```
media = Column(ARRAY(JSON)) # this field has array of jsons.
```

I want to validate this using pydantic schemas.
currently I am doing following.

```
media : List(Dict)  # Dict from typing
```

but when I am trying to insert values in media. 
I get the following  error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch) column "media" is of type json[] but expression is of type text[]
```

Comment: Check `CastingArray` recipe from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479654/issue-with-sqlalchemy-and-inserting-array-of-jsonb-to-postgresql

Comment: @IljaEverilä that doesn't help.

Comment: In that case provide a bit more information on how you are inserting the data (a [mcve]).

Comment: Same here, but only on windows. Works on my mac.